# Can a Mongo-Express container connect to MongoDB with TLS?

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose, tls1.2, mongo-express

I have a mongo container, started with the `requireTLS` TLS mode, and a mongo-express container. Mongo-express does not seem to manage to connect to mongo using TLS.

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3.1'
services:
  mongodb1:
    image          : "mongo:4.2"
    container_name : "mongodb-001"
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME : "admin"
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD : "adminpasswd"
    volumes:
      - "./mongo-data:/data/db"
      - "./etc_mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf"
      - "./certificates:/etc/certificates:ro"
    command:
      - "--tlsMode"
      - "preferTLS"
      - "--tlsDisabledProtocols"
      - "none"
      - "--tlsCertificateKeyFile"
      - "/etc/certificates/certificateKey.pem"
      - "--tlsCAFile"
      - "/etc/certificates/CA.crt"
      - "--tlsAllowConnectionsWithoutCertificates"

  mongo-express:
    image          : "mongo-express:latest"
    container_name : "mongo-express-001"
    ports:
      - '8081:8081'
    depends_on:
      - mongodb1
    volumes:
      - "./certificates/CA.crt:/etc/certificates/CA.crt:ro"
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: "mongodb-001"
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT: "27017"
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN: "false"
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_AUTH_DATABASE: "admin"
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_AUTH_USERNAME: "admin"
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_AUTH_PASSWORD: "adminpasswd"
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: "admin"
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: "adminpasswd"
      ME_CONFIG_SITE_SSL_ENABLED: "true"
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_CA_FILE: "/etc/certificates/CA.crt"
```

...and the error message I get:

```
mongodb-001      | 2020-10-09T14:16:13.299+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.31.0.3:44774 #2 (1 connection now open)
mongodb-001      | 2020-10-09T14:16:13.305+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn2] Error receiving request from client: SSLHandshakeFailed: The server is configured to only allow SSL connections. Ending connection from 172.31.0.3:44774 (connection id: 2)
mongodb-001      | 2020-10-09T14:16:13.305+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn2] end connection 172.31.0.3:44774 (0 connections now open)
mongo-express-001 | 
mongo-express-001 | /node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:265
mongo-express-001 |         process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
mongo-express-001 |                                       ^
mongo-express-001 | Error [MongoError]: connection 0 to mongodb-001:27017 closed
mongo-express-001 |     at Function.MongoError.create (/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:29:11)
mongo-express-001 |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:200:22)
mongo-express-001 |     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
mongo-express-001 |     at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
mongo-express-001 |     at TCP.<anonymous> (net.js:674:12)
mongo-express-001 exited with code 1
```

Note that:

- I can connect to MongoDB using a mongo shell with the same parameters I pass to mongo-express:

```sh
mongo "mongodb://admin:adminpasswd@mongodb-001:27017/admin?authSource=admin" --tls --tlsCAFile certificates/CA.crt
```

- If I start MongoDB in `preferTLS` mode, the mongo-express connection works

Comment: You do not have tls enabled on the client.

Comment: @D. SM: I thought maybe ME_CONFIG_SITE_SSL_ENABLED was enough. OK, how can I enable TLS on the mongo-express side? I have tried replacing the server and port environment variables with `ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL = "mongodb://admin:adminpasswd@mongodb-001:27017/admin?tls=true"`, but it still gives the same error.

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: I read the documentation here https://github.com/mongo-express/mongo-express and I cannot find anything explicit about TLS, but feel free to point out, if I have missed something (I am really not an expert on TLS/SSL). Are you suggesting adding `tls=true` in the connection URI does not enable TLS on the mongo-express side?

Comment: I am not familiar with mongo-express and my attempt to get it working failed, `tls=true` should be recognized by recent MongoDB drivers, what m-e does I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Create a new `config.js` file with the following code

```
module.exports = {
  mongodb: {
    connectionOptions: {
      ssl: true,
    }
  }
};
```

and mount that file in your docker compose file at `/node_modules/mongo-express/config.js`

## Explanation

It appears to be an issue with their config.default.js file. In it, they have this

```
module.exports = {                                                                                                     
  mongodb: {                                                                                                           
    // if a connection string options such as server/port/etc are ignored
    connectionString: mongo.connectionString || getConnectionStringFromEnvVariables(),
                                                                                                                   
    connectionOptions: {                              
    // ssl: connect to the server using secure SSL
    ssl: process.env.ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SSL || mongo.ssl,
                                                                                                                   
    // sslValidate: validate mongod server certificate against CA
    sslValidate: process.env.ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SSLVALIDATE || true,
                                                                                                                   
    // sslCA: array of valid CA certificates                                                                         
    sslCA: sslCAFromEnv ? [sslCAFromEnv] : [],

    // autoReconnect: automatically reconnect if connection is lost                                 
    autoReconnect: true,                                                                                             
                                                                                                                   
    // poolSize: size of connection pool (number of connections to use)
    poolSize: 4,                                   
  }
}
```

You'll notice the existence of an env var that's not listed (with reason) in their documentation. `ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SSL`

This is required to enable tls support. Setting the env var yourself however does nothing but throw an error and break express due to it not being cast to a Boolean. So it just reads as a string 'true' or 'false'.

This code is fixed in their npm package code, but they haven't updated their docker image since late 2021. So the only "fix" I've found for this is to create a new `config.js` file with the following code

```
module.exports = {
  mongodb: {
    connectionOptions: {
      ssl: true,
      sslValidate: true,
    }
  }
};
```

Then mount this file at `/node_modules/mongo-express/config.js` in your docker-compose file. It'll read these and overwrite the defaults.

Note: I added the `sslValidate` key:value pair as well due to the fact that it suffers from the same lack of type casting. So if you omit the `ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SSLVALIDATE` env var entirely, it'll be set as true, but if you include the env var as either true or false, it'll just simply break (undefined behaviour).

Answer (score 0):

Connection from mongo-express starts to work better when both are in the same docker network, like

```
docker network create netw1
docker network connect netw1 mongo
docker network connect netw1 mongo-exprs
```

And network can be defined with suitable arguments

```
docker network create --attachable --internal netw1
```